# SQL - sum of column

Tags: sql, sum

I'm trying to create a SQL query that will sum column that have the same No_. How can I sum the Quantity?

```
select  Item.No_, Entry.[Posting Date], Entry.Quantity, MinMax.Maximum
FROM Item
 join Entry
 on Item.No_ = Entry.[Item No_]
 join MinMax
 on Item.No_ = MinMax.Item No_
```

The output:

[image]

but I want the output is sum of Quantity 10+5=15

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `group by` and `sum()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following although without test information the group by may not be correct/ work as expected.

```
select  Item.No_, Entry.[Posting Date], Sum(Entry.Quantity) as TotalQuantity, MinMax.Maximum
FROM Item
join Entry
on Item.No_ = Entry.[Item No_]
join MinMax
on Item.No_ = MinMax.Item No_
Group By Item.No_, Entry.[Posting Date], MinMax.Maximum
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sum()` function:

```
SELECT  sum(Entry.quantity) as sum_quantity
FROM Item
    JOIN Entry ON Item.No_ = Entry.[Item No_]
    JOIN MinMaxON Item.No_ = MinMax.Item No_
```